How do I calculate a new column according to a criteria in R?
Suppose I have data:
ID <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
t <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
number <- c(0.5,0.4,0.1,0.3,0.25,0.45)
dat <- cbind(ID,t,number)

     ID t number
[1,]  1 1   0.50
[2,]  2 1   0.40
[3,]  3 1   0.10
[4,]  1 2   0.30
[5,]  2 2   0.25
[6,]  3 2   0.45

I want to calculate the fourth column: If the ID is not 1, then the number of the fourth column should be number × the number of ID=1. For example, my desired result should be
     ID t number  calc
[1,]  1 1   0.50    NA
[2,]  2 1   0.40 0.200
[3,]  3 1   0.10 0.050
[4,]  1 2   0.30    NA
[5,]  2 2   0.25 0.075
[6,]  3 2   0.45 0.135

where 0.2=0.4×0.5, 0.05=0.1×0.5, 0.75=0.25×0.3, 0.135=0.3×0.45

Assuming you are ok to have your data being a data frame, you can do:
library(tidyverse)

ID <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
t <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
number <- c(0.5,0.4,0.1,0.3,0.25,0.45)
dat <- data.frame(ID,t,number)

dat %>%
  group_by(t) %>%
  mutate(calc = if_else(ID != 1, number * number[ID == 1], NA_real_)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 4
     ID     t number   calc
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     1   0.5  NA    
2     2     1   0.4   0.2  
3     3     1   0.1   0.05 
4     1     2   0.3  NA    
5     2     2   0.25  0.075
6     3     2   0.45  0.135


Some options using base for dat = data.frame(ID, t, number):
dat$calc = unlist(tapply(dat, ~t, \(i) with(i, number*number[ID==1]*NA^(ID==1))))     

giving
> dat
  ID t number  calc
1  1 1   0.50    NA
2  2 1   0.40 0.200
3  3 1   0.10 0.050
4  1 2   0.30    NA
5  2 2   0.25 0.075
6  3 2   0.45 0.135

or
tapply(dat[-2], dat[2], transform, calc=number*number[NA^(ID==1)]) |> array2DF()


or
do.call("rbind", tapply(dat[-2], dat[2], transform, calc=number*number[NA^(ID==1)]))


You can try
dat %>%
  mutate(calc = number * number[ID == 1] * NA^(ID == 1), .by = t)

or
dat %>%
  mutate(calc = number * number[ifelse(ID == 1, NA, 1)], .by = t)

or
dat %>%
  mutate(calc = number * number[NA^(ID == 1)], .by = t)

which gives
  ID t number  calc
1  1 1   0.50    NA
2  2 1   0.40 0.200
3  3 1   0.10 0.050
4  1 2   0.30    NA
5  2 2   0.25 0.075
6  3 2   0.45 0.135


Calculate cal by group with ave and replace ID == 1 cols with NA.
> dat |> 
+   transform(cal=replace(ave(number, t, FUN=\(x) el(x[ID == 1]))*number, ID == 1, NA))
  ID t number   cal
1  1 1   0.50    NA
2  2 1   0.40 0.200
3  3 1   0.10 0.050
4  1 2   0.30    NA
5  2 2   0.25 0.075
6  3 2   0.45 0.135

Note, that this results in a data.frame so you might want to pipe this into an |> as.matrix() to coerce back.

Another base option (with dat = data.frame(ID, t, number)):
transform(
  dat,
  calc = ifelse(ID == 1, NA, number[cummax((1:nrow(dat))*(ID == 1))]*number)
)

or, using NA^
transform(
  dat,
  calc = number[cummax((1:nrow(dat))*(ID == 1))]*number*NA^(ID == 1)
)

A couple data.table options:
library(data.table)

setDT(dat)[ID == 1, calc := number][,calc := nafill(calc, "locf")*number*NA^(ID == 1)]

or
setDT(dat)[,calc := c(NA, number[1]*number[-1]), cumsum(ID == 1)]

